# Restarting Angular app with a button in HTML file

Tags: angular, button, reset

I am making an app that takes in a form and writes it out to a file. Is there a way to add a Reset button that restarts the app, like the refresh button in the browser so the user can start over after they already submitted?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

Comment: yes, but i wonder why you'd want to force the user to wait for a reload when you can just reset the form for them...

Comment: to @bryan60 point, there is overhead with reloading the entire angular application. if you goal is to merely reset a form. then you can use `form.reset()` to reset the form and allow the user to re-use the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just force browser to reload the page with

```
window.location.reload(true)
```